# Angular Detect Changes Issue

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm having issues with fixture.detectChanges(); I would have this beforeEach.

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Testcomponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.numArr = [1]; // numArr is an @Input 
     fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Then in a test case I would have something that pushes to that array.

```
it('update correctly', () => {
    component.numArr.push(2);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let numbers = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('nums'))
    expect(numbers.length).toEqual(component.numArr.length);
})
```

The css query would return 1 whereas the length of numArr is 2. It seems to only update after the first fixture.detectChanges(). Any subsequent call would not update.

Edit: I saw this http://www.bentedder.com/fixture-detectChanges-not-working-angular-4-karma-tests/. And it does not seem like a good answer as I am trying to test when the var gets updated.

Edit2: HTML

```
<div>
 <select >
  <option class="nums" *ngFor="let num of numArr" [ngValue]="num" >
    {{num}}
  </option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the html with 'nums'? otherwise it's not clear where the error might be

Comment: Edited in the HTML